# Need help understanding parameters

Tags: javascript

Hello I was looking at this problem, and I am having trouble understanding how JavaScript knows which parameter color is in the anonymous function.  Does the it know because of the context of what's in the function?  The answer btw is that it prints out 3, 6, 9.

```
var numbers = [0,1,2...]
var colors = ["red", "blue, ..."]

numbers.forEach(function(color){
    if(color % 3 === 0) {
        console.log(color);
    }
```

});

Comment: numbers is an array that is iterable by the foreach function.

Foreach takes as a parameter an annonymous function, which itself takes a parameter.  The for each function applies your annonymous function to every element in the numbers array.

Comment: @FredMan Is colors not an iterable array?

Comment: @Quentin I looked at the other article you linked this one to, and it definitely didn't answer my question... at least to me.

Comment: You are passing a callback function (`function(color){`). You want to know where the value of the `color` argument comes from. The duplicate question definitely answers that.

Comment: @Quentin I think part of the problem with the example you sent me is that I don't fully understand the code.